# Counting Different cells that are the same for a list

Tags: excel-formula, automatic-ref-counting, counting, countif

I have to draw up panel setups for work and a lot of time goes into counting/listing how many of each panels there are, I've been looking into "count if" formulas and such with little success, so attached is an image with a few panels and a list how would I write a formula that would automatically tell me how many of each panels there are.

[image]

## The cells are Merged

I have tried copying from YouTube a color counting formula but for some reason, it doesn't work

Comment: What does `=COUNTIF(T:AN,E6)` give you?

Comment: It gives me a "There's a problem with this formula."

Comment: @Teddi This is a US website so we kind of agree to use a comma as the Excel list separator. Maybe your list separator is a semicolon i.e. `=COUNTIF(T:AN;E6)`.